# Building of Dolphin emulator on Ubuntu 16.10 fails at OpenGL linking

Tags: ubuntu, opengl

I'm trying to compile the Dolphin emulator by myself on Ubuntu 16.10 because of a compatibility issue with PIE. I think this question is suitable for SE since it looks like a configuration issue rather than a problem with Dolphin.

The building process works fine until it comes to the OpenGL part. The first issue was that the build failed because of missing includes `<GL/glx.h`. I'm using the proprietary Nvidia driver and I found this include in `/usr/include/nvidia-375`. I tried a quick hack by creating a symlink in `/usr/include` to it but then another error appeared and it seemed like this headers are incompatible in some way. I got rid of this error by installing `mesa-common-dev`. (This looks a little bit fishy to me) But now the build fails at the linking stage like this:

```
(....snip....)
[ 63%] Built target videovulkan
[ 65%] Built target videosoftware
[ 65%] Built target videonull
[ 66%] Built target videoogl
[ 70%] Built target videocommon
[ 90%] Built target core
[ 91%] Built target uicommon
[ 91%] Linking CXX executable ../../../Binaries/dolphin-emu
../Common/libcommon.a(GLX.cpp.o): In function `cInterfaceGLX::ClearCurrent()':
GLX.cpp:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `glXMakeCurrent'
../Common/libcommon.a(GLX.cpp.o): In function `cInterfaceGLX::Shutdown()':
GLX.cpp:(.text+0x6b): undefined reference to `glXDestroyContext'
../Common/libcommon.a(GLX.cpp.o): In function `cInterfaceGLX::Create(void*, bool)':
GLX.cpp:(.text+0x11f): undefined reference to `glXQueryVersion'
GLX.cpp:(.text+0x1ee): undefined reference to `glXGetProcAddress'
GLX.cpp:(.text+0x314): undefined reference to `glXChooseFBConfig'
GLX.cpp:(.text+0x3d8): undefined reference to `glXGetVisualFromFBConfig'
../Common/libcommon.a(GLX.cpp.o): In function `cInterfaceGLX::MakeCurrent()':
GLX.cpp:(.text+0x6c9): undefined reference to `glXMakeCurrent'
../Common/libcommon.a(GLX.cpp.o): In function `cInterfaceGLX::GetFuncAddress(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>$
GLX.cpp:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `glXGetProcAddress'
../Common/libcommon.a(GLX.cpp.o): In function `cInterfaceGLX::Swap()':
GLX.cpp:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `glXSwapBuffers'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Source/Core/DolphinWX/CMakeFiles/dolphin-emu.dir/build.make:2343: recipe for target 'Binaries/dolphin-emu' failed
make[2]: *** [Binaries/dolphin-emu] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1531: recipe for target 'Source/Core/DolphinWX/CMakeFiles/dolphin-emu.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [Source/Core/DolphinWX/CMakeFiles/dolphin-emu.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The only result of my research to this error is that the order of compiler arguments is wrong but first of all it's hard to believe this since this would mean that no build would ever succeed. And I don't know where I could search for this since the project is quite huge and I only have basic understanding of cmake.

My conclusion is that there must be something else I overlooked but I can't figure it out. What's going wrong here?

Comment: "undefined reference" means "required library not found". It has nothing to do with headers. glX lives in `libGL.so`. Be aware that Nvidia may have its own version and symlink.

Comment: How about if you add the nvidia library path to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable?

Comment: @vincent I found a `libglx.so` at `/usr/lib/nvidia-375/xorg` so I startet the make process again with `env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-375/xorg make` but with the same result. Or should I start over with cmake?

Comment: Might as well try it from the beginning and make sure everything has been cleaned. GLX.cpp and any file using the GLX.cpp.o will need access to the glx library.

Comment: What version of dolphin are you trying to build?

Comment: Okay I got the error. There was a dependency missing: `libglu1-mesa-dev`. Something went wrong while I installed it with a bunch of other packets. I still don't get it why I need the mesa stuff with the proprietary Nvidia driver but it's working now. Anyway, thanks for your input. Without re-executing cmake and carefully reading the output I wouldn't have found the error. It's interesting that cmake succeeds even when no OpenGL was found on Linux...